# Host multiple asp.net core web application under a single linux server

Tags: linux, apache, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new to asp.net core. I read the whole Microsoft official document and able to host the application in Linux Apache server. But I want to host multiple asp.net core web applications under a single IP Address. Please, anyone have the solution post here.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-apache) shows us a way to use Apache as a reverse proxy :

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}helloapp-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}helloapp-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Basically, this configuration will make Apache listens on `*:80` and proxy any HttpRequest whose `ServerName` equals `www.example.com` to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`.

This is how Apache used as an proxy to ASP.NET Core works.

As for your question, suppose you have two asp.net core web applications:

1. the first one is called `WebApp1` and listens on `0.0.0.0:5000` .
2. and the other is called `WebApp2` and listens on `0.0.0.0:6000` .

Your Apache server listens on `0.0.0.0:80`. For any incoming http request,

- when `Host` equals `www.webapp1.org`,  proxy this request to `0.0.0.0:5000`
- when `Host` equals `www.webapp2.org`,  proxy this request to `0.0.0.0:6000`

So  you could add two proxies :

proxy 1 :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ServerName www.webapp1.org
    ServerAlias *.webapp1.org
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}webapp1-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}webapp1-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

proxy 2 :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:6000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:6000/
    ServerName www.webapp2.org
    ServerAlias *.webapp2.org
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}webapp1-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}webapp2-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: yes its work for me. But without www extension, it by default go to 5001 port

Comment: @saswatsaubhagya  if you're using `https` instead of `http`, the default port is `5001`. Anyway, custom this configuration as you like :)

Comment: thanks, what about the kestrel service file, Do I need to have 1 file for each website running asp.net core?